# How to apply filter to get elements which have same value in JSONobjects inside JSON array using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, intersection

I have a JSON array with multiple(dynamic) JSON objects. I need to compare the objects and pick the keys which has the same value in all the objects. My JSON looks like,

```
[
    {
        "CreateAccountName":"Joseph",
        "CreateDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Description":"Utilization of services",
        "Type":2,
        "Id":1000000001,
        "Count":1,
        "ModifiedAccountName":"",
        "ModifiedDateTime":"2016-10-04T10:16:40.5190025",
        "Name":"Utilization of services",
        "CardCount":0,
        "Target":95,
        "UniversalId":"SDFOPIJ-SDFGLKJ-ER234-234LF",
        "AccountId":0,
        "AccountName":"Joseph"
    },

    {
        "CreateAccountName":"Joseph",
        "CreateDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Description":"Utilization of Food",
        "Type":2,
        "Id":1000000001,
        "Count":1,
        "ModifiedAccountName":"",
        "ModifiedDateTime":"2016-10-04T10:16:40.5190025",
        "Name":"Utilization of Food",
        "CardCount":0,
        "Target":95,
        "UniversalId":"SDFOPIJ-SDFGLKJ-ER234-234LF",
        "AccountId":0,
        "AccountName":"Joseph"
    },

    {
        "CreateAccountName":"Joseph",
        "CreateDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Description":"Utilization of services",
        "Type":2,
        "Id":1000000001,
        "Count":1,
        "ModifiedAccountName":"",
        "ModifiedDateTime":"2016-10-04T10:16:40.5190025",
        "Name":"Utilization of services",
        "CardCount":0,
        "Target":95,
        "UniversalId":"SDFOPIJ-SDFGLKJ-ER234-234LF",
        "AccountId":0,
        "AccountName":"Joseph"
    }
]
```

I want to get the Keys which has same value. Example, CreateAccountName. It has same value in all the objects.

The tricky case is, the key itself dynamic. I cannot hardcode the key and do compare. The key name may change or another set of keys may come. I am looking for a generic solution to compare and get the "intersection" of the objects.

Comment: You should iterate over the list and store the key and value array  in a different object  and then check if that particular key has all same values or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this just with `Array.reduce()`

```js
var json = [
    {
        "CreateAccountName":"Joseph",
        "CreateDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Description":"Utilization of services",
        "Type":2,
        "Id":1000000001,
        "Count":1,
        "ModifiedAccountName":"",
        "ModifiedDateTime":"2016-10-04T10:16:40.5190025",
        "Name":"Utilization of services",
        "CardCount":0,
        "Target":95,
        "UniversalId":"SDFOPIJ-SDFGLKJ-ER234-234LF",
        "AccountId":0,
        "AccountName":"Joseph"
    },

    {
        "CreateAccountName":"Joseph",
        "CreateDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Description":"Utilization of Food",
        "Type":2,
        "Id":1000000001,
        "Count":1,
        "ModifiedAccountName":"",
        "ModifiedDateTime":"2016-10-04T10:16:40.5190025",
        "Name":"Utilization of Food",
        "CardCount":0,
        "Target":95,
        "UniversalId":"SDFOPIJ-SDFGLKJ-ER234-234LF",
        "AccountId":0,
        "AccountName":"Joseph"
    },

    {
        "CreateAccountName":"Joseph",
        "CreateDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Description":"Utilization of services",
        "Type":2,
        "Id":1000000001,
        "Count":1,
        "ModifiedAccountName":"",
        "ModifiedDateTime":"2016-10-04T10:16:40.5190025",
        "Name":"Utilization of services",
        "CardCount":0,
        "Target":95,
        "UniversalId":"SDFOPIJ-SDFGLKJ-ER234-234LF",
        "AccountId":0,
        "AccountName":"Joseph"
    }
];

var intersection = json.reduce(function(result, item) {
  Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
    if(! item.hasOwnProperty(key) || item[key] !== result[key]) delete result[key];
  });
  return result;
});

console.log(intersection)
```